# What's the difference between $3^{3^{3^3}}$ and $27^{27}\;$?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

Why does $\;\large3^{3^{3^3}}\;$ evaluate to a larger number than $\;\large 27^{27}$?

Comment: The first one can be written $3^{3^{3^3}} = 3^{3^{27}} = 3^{7625597484987}$. The other one is $27^{27} = (3^3)^{27} = 3^{3\cdot 27} = 3^{81}$. Clearly the first one is much bigger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One is $$(3^3)^{3^3}$$ while the other is $$3^{3^{3^3}}$$

What is the difference between $$3^{3^3}$$ and $${(3^3)}^{3}\text{ ?}$$

In the first one, you make $3^3$, and then raise $3$ to that power.

In the other, first take $3^3$, and raise that to the power of $3$. See the difference?

Answer (score 24):

Big letters only used for visibility:

### $$3^{3^{3^3}} = 3^{3^{27}} \ne 3^{3^4} = 3^{3 \cdot 3^3} = (3^3)^{3^3} = 27^{27}$$

Answer (score 14):

In short: $$\Large 3^{3^{3^3}} = \color{blue}{\bf 3^{3^{27}}} \neq 27^{27} = 3^{{3\times 3}^3} = \color{blue}{\bf {3^3}^4}$$

ADDED: The expression to the left is called a ***[tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)***. You can see it *tetration* compared to exponentiation  and other operations, plus lots of information about such expressions at the linked Wikipedia entry.

Comment: User 70366 - Do you understand that in general, $(a^b)^c = a^{bc} \neq a^{b^c}$, and so, for example in this case, we need only look at $(3^3)^3 = 3^{3\times 3} \neq 3^{3^3}$? The same applies to *tetrations* of more than three exponents.

Comment: The most paradigm-breaking thing in this answer is that it has shown me that I can change colors in MSE. Although obvious, I never thought about it.

Comment: Thanks, @Gustavo: Color is really useful at times! Is the use of color worth an upvote? ;-)

Comment: Right away, sir!

Comment: @GustavoMarra You wanna change that to "ma'am"!

Comment: Hehehe, I didn't know, sorry :P Ma'am it is!

Comment: Like your colored answer. Blue means deep to me. +1

Comment: @Babak Yes, and $\color{blue}{\bf blue}$ is my favorite color! $\color{blue}{\bf \ddot\smile \;\;!}$